# Can I replace a 1N5347 diode with a 1N5374?

Tags: diodes

I'm building an EPROM burner and ended up with the wrong bill of materials, meaning that I have purchased 1N5374 diodes instead of 1N5347. Can I safely use the 1N5374 instead?

I understand from the datasheet that the 1N5347 has a nominal zener voltage of 10 V and a maximum reverse leakage current of 5 μA at 7.2 V, whereas the 1N5374 has a nominal zener voltage of 75 V and a maximum reverse leakage current of 0.5 μA at 54 V.

Comment: No, absolutely not.

Comment: Looks like they are out of stock everywhere. But maybe you can use some other Zener that is also 10V.

Comment: please show us the schematic of the EPROM burner.

Comment: @BruceAbbott https://github.com/svenpetersen1965/C64-Promenade-Model-D

Comment: Wrong reference to 1N5474 in the title, instead of 1N5374, has been corrected.

Comment: Leakage current is not measured in volts.

Comment: Oh, I found one that will probably work. https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/nte-electronics-inc/1N5347B/11654769

Answer (score 1):

> Can I safely use the 1N5374 instead?

No, you can't!

As you yourself have mentioned, 1N5347 is a 10 V Zener diode whereas 1N5374 is a 75 V one.